# Cumulative Percentages for different datas in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have different datas and I want to calculate cumulative percentages of each data. I used formula "=B1/$B$2145*100" for a data which has 2145 rows. But when I import another data which has less rows, it gives "#DIV/0" error. Kindly suggest any excel function or vba macro script which can change formula's absolute reference($B$2145) according to data rows.

Answer (score 1):

For Excel versions that support Dynamic Arrays,

```
=LET(dat,FILTER(B:B,B:B<>""),Last,INDEX(dat,COUNTA(dat)),dat/Last*100)
```

Or, if you have a header in row 1

```
=LET(dat,FILTER(B:B,(B:B<>"")*(ROW(B:B)>1)),Last,INDEX(dat,COUNTA(dat)),dat/Last*100)
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are looking for is:

```
=B1/LOOKUP(2,1/ (B:B<>""),B:B)*100
```

Find more details here: https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell